# Unity memory profiler shows a texture is referenced by a material, but it's not

Tags: unity-game-engine, reference

In a snapshot of the Memory Profiler, it says this texture "blush" is referenced by 2 materials.
[image]

I clicked the "Select in Editor" button, and the inspector highlighted the Material. And as far as I can tell, it does not reference the blush texture, but using the default particle texture under "Maps".

[image]

I tried this procedure with another texture "skull5" in the snapshot, and it seems working fine.

[image]
[image]

The question is how does the material reference the "blush" texture? How can I delete the reference? I don't want that texture to be included in the build and in the memory when the game started. Thanks!